# How to spin 3 dimensions array actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array

I have a 3 dimensions array like this (Instead of 0's I have objects):

```
var array:Array =
  [
    [
      [0,0],[0,0],[0,0]
    ],
    [
      [0,0],[0,0],[0,0]
    ],
    [
      [0,0],[0,0],[0,0]
    ],
    [
      [0,0],[0,0],[0,0]
    ]
  ];
```

Every array position contains an object placed in a 3D space and to locate it you only need: array[zPos][yPos][xPos].

Is it there a library or a function that allow me to spin the array 90 degrees in the Z, Y and/or X axis?

Note: Remember the array could be irregular.

EDIT:

I don't think I have made myself clear. I do not want to move objects in a 3D space, I only want to know they are there. What I want to do it to operate with the array.

I've found a partial solution to my problem but I believe it could be optimized. I've developed a formula to spin the multiple array by the Z axis. Here it's the code:

```
var arr1:Array = 
[
    [
        [  0,   1,   2,   3],
        [010, 011, 012, 013]
    ],
    [
        [100, 101, 102, 103],
        [110, 111, 112, 113]
    ],
    [
        [200, 201, 202, 203],
        [210, 211, 212, 213]
    ]
];
var arr2:Array = new Array;

for (var i:int = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) 
{
    arr2.push(new Array);
    for (var j:int = 0; j < arr1[i][0].length; j++) 
    {
        arr2[i].push(new Array);
        for (var k:int = 0; k < arr1[i].length; k++) 
        {
            arr2[i][j].push(0);
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) 
{
    for (j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; j++) 
    {
        for (k = 0; k < arr1[i][j].length; k++) 
        {
            arr2[i][k][arr1[i].length - j - 1] = arr1[i][j][k];
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know other formulas of libraries to rotate the multiple array by the axis Y or X?
Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Comment: Im not quite sure what your trying to achieve, but im pretty sure you can do this with away3d: http://away3d.com/ - you would place all of your objects in a 3d container and then spin that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to reconsider your design. Putting objects in an array like that and trying to rotate them will be a definite performance killer.

For multidimensional array rotations, integers or numbers, the proper way is to use a rotation matrix. You will find functions for 3D operations like that in many popular actionscript engines like alternativa3d, away3d etc.